# simple jquery slideshow script - Is there something wrong with my jquery syntax?

Tags: jquery, syntax, slideshow

> > > `var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();`
> > >
> > > > `j$(document).ready(function(){`
> > > >
> > > > > `j$.fn.slideShow = function(timeOut){`
> > > > >
> > > > > > `var $slidecontainer = this;`
> > > > > >             `this.children(':gt(0)').hide();`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > `setInterval(function() {`
> > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > `$slidecontainer.children().eq(0).fadeOut(2000).next().fadeIn(2000).addClass('on').nextAll().removeClass('on').end().appendTo($slidecontainer);}, timeOut || 1000);`
> > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > ***`var imgheight = this.children('.on').outerHeight();`
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > >                   `this.css('height', imgheight );`
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > >                   `};`***
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > >                   `j$(function() {`
> > > > > > > > >                   `j$('.slideshow').slideShow(7000);});`
> > > > > > > > >                   `});`

For the most part the above script works well. The only problem is the css for image height isn't being applied to the parent container. When I try this in the browser console it works perfectly. When I have the script called in the page it doesn't apply the image height. It does everything else though.

this is the html

> > > `<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">`
> > >       `<img width="970" height="300" src="someimage.jpg" class="" >`
> > >       `<img width="970" height="300" src="someimage.jpg" class="" >`
> > >       `<img width="970" height="300" src="someimage.jpg" class="" >`
> > >       `<img width="970" height="300" src="someimage.jpg" class="" >`
> > >       `<img width="970" height="300" src="someimage.jpg" class="" >`
> > >       `</div>`

The following turned out to be the answer:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$.fn.slideShow = function (timeOut) {

    var $slidecontainer = this;
    $slidecontainer.children(':gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {

        $slidecontainer.children().eq(0).fadeOut(2000).next().fadeIn(2000).addClass('on').nextAll().removeClass('on').end().end().appendTo($slidecontainer);
    }, timeOut || 1000);

    var imgheight =  $slidecontainer.children('img').first().outerHeight();   
     $slidecontainer.css('height', imgheight);
};
j$(window).load(function () {
   j$('.slideshow').slideShow(7000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
       <img width="970" height="300" src="s_logo_lg.gif" class="" >
       <img width="970" height="300" src="lg.gif" class="" >
       <img width="970" height="300" src="es_logo_lg.gif" class="" >
       <img width="970" height="300" src="g.gif" class="" >
       <img width="970" height="300" src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" class="" >
 </div>
```

---

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$.fn.slideShow = function (timeOut) {

    var $slidecontainer = this;
    this.children(':gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {

        $slidecontainer.children().eq(0).fadeOut(2000).next().fadeIn(2000).addClass('on').nextAll().removeClass('on').end().end().appendTo($slidecontainer);
    }, timeOut || 1000);

    var imgheight = this.children('img').first().outerHeight();   
    this.css('height', imgheight);
};
j$(window).load(function () {

    j$(function () {
        j$('.slideshow').slideShow(7000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RTZK6/

$(window).load ensures that images are loaded, so that their hieght calcualtion goes fine in all browsers. You can specifically look for each img element also.

Looks like you missed one end(), you selected next() and then nextAl() so you will need two end() to point selection back to current element.

Updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RTZK6/2/

Comment: didn't work... still not applying the image height to the parent container

Comment: did you put class="on" for any element initially? Looks like you havent, and you are trying to get height of $('.on')

Comment: no I haven't put the default "on" class. The list of images is generated from a list of wordpress posts. so if I add that to the code, then it will apply the "on" class to all items

Comment: then simpley do var imgheight = this.children('img').outerHeight(); if all images are of same height

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but isn't the class being applied before I declare the variable imgheight??

Comment: That won't work. For the slideshow to work properly, the images get set to position absolute, and display inline. This means the images have no height. Only the active (class="on") slide has a height which can be calculated.

Comment: No you are caling it asynchronously inside the anunymous function which is first parameter to  setInterval which will be invoked after 1000ms. The height css is called right away.

Comment: ok, so basically I need to declare the height variable after the slideshow starts running.... how would I go about doing that?

Comment: No just see the updated answer, just use this.children('img').first() to get the first image, otherwise your container will remain heightless for 1000ms.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this`, instead of use `$slidecontainer` or `$(this)`

You have already assigned this to $slidecontainer variable.